# Hide iframe if height is 150px

Tags: javascript

I have an iframe which is loading external content dynamically from a site I have control of.

In case no content is available I load an empty page.

Unfortunately an iframe has a height of 150px.

How can I at best with Javascript define to hide the mother div (container) or iframe in case the iframe has the standard size of 150px?

```
<div id="container">

<iframe src=""> </iframe>

</div>
```

Comment: `<iframe>` has the size you set for it, it doesn't matter what's inside. Which also means that if it has a different height than its default, that was set by you, and you could very well hide/show it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **client.Height** to get the Height of an element (with padding, the border is not included)

Try this:

```
const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
let iframeHeight = iframe.clientHeight;

if (iframeHeight == 150) {
    iframe.style.display = "none";
}
```

It will be hide the first iframe with standard height. Let me know for more requirements. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
window.getComputedStyle(element);
```

And it will give you an object with all css properties of that element.

 
If you want to get the height:

```
window.getComputedStyle(element).height;
```

And that will return ’150px’, or whatever else the height will be

 
*Note: typing ‘window’ is not required, getComputedStyle() will also work*